# Convert BigQuery's legacy SQL to standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to convert below code from legacy to standard SQL. The code is in Legacy SQL (Big Query). Here is the code:

```
MAX(IF((hi.Info.Action='complete'),1, 0)) WITHIN RECORD AS transact
```

what will be the equivalent for standard SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#legacySQL
SELECT 
  MAX(IF((hi.Info.Action='complete'),1, 0)) WITHIN RECORD AS transact
FROM table
```

will be

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  (SELECT MAX(IF(Info.Action='complete',1, 0)) FROM UNNEST(hi)) AS transact
FROM table
```

Note: I assumed that `hi` is REPEATED RECORD and `info` is RECORD